# Ошибка IndentationError: unexpected indent в простейшем калькуляторе

Tags: python

Я хочу что бы после ввода двух чисел пользователь мог выбрать операцию (сложение, умножение, вычитание или деление). Но загвостка произошла сразу, после предложения выбрать операцию (в данном случае сложение) вылетает ошибка:

```
File "Culculate.py", line 12
    if num == '+':
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
(venv) iMac-Petr:2020 petr$
```

Помогите кто чем может. Ниже сам код.

```
a = float(input("Enter First number: "))
b = float(input('Enter second number: '))


sum = a + b
minus = a - b
umnojenie = a * b
delenie = a / b


num = input('Chose process: \n+ \n- \n* \n /\n')
    if num == '+':
        print (sum)
```

Comment: Совет 1. Переведите текст ошибки; Совет 2. Почитайте учебник по Python.
В Python имеет очень большое значение отступ строки (слева) - это одна из синтаксических основ языка (как фигурные скобки с C-подобных языках)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python - язык со строгим отношением к отступам. Отступ в строке с if не нужен.
Должно быть так:

```
num = input('Chose process: \n+ \n- \n* \n /\n')
if num == '+':
    print (sum)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Но теперь появляется такая ошибка        
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Culculate.py", line 11, in <module>
    num = input('Chose process: \n+ \n- \n* \n /\n')
    File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @Petr_Anisimov Странно. Я проверил в Google Colab, у меня никакой ошибки не возникает с вашим кодом.

Comment: @Petr_Anisimov У меня есть только один вариант - что у вас не хватает перевода строки в конце файла, например.

Comment: @Petr_Anisimov, такая ошибка может возникнуть если вы где-то скобку забыли закрыть, например если у вас в конце `print (sum` вместо `print (sum)`

Comment: Очень странно у меня тоже все получилось в Google Colab. А в PYCHARM не выходит. В любом случае спасибо за ответ!)